# 1-10 survey questions and options on a mobile device

Tags: mobile, design, surveys

Many survey questions ask the respondent to choose one option from 10 (e.g. the Net Promoter Score).

However Apple's HIG recommend that touch targets on mobile have a minimum of 44x44pts.

So we have 44x10 = 440, which is greater than, e.g. the iPhone6 Plus which has a width of 414 points.

Any design recommendations here, given that a responsive overflow design with buttons probably wouldn't work for most surveys, e.g.

```
 Not at all likely [0] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ] [ 7 ] [ 8 ] [ 9 ] [ 10 ] Extremely likely
```

would become

```
  Not at all likely [ 0 ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ]
                    [ 6 ] [ 7 ] [ 8 ] [ 9 ] [ 10 ] Extremely likely
```

which might influence the user's response.

Comment: Do you really need 1-10? How about 1-5 or 1-4?

Comment: There are multiple reasons - sensitivity and compatibility with previous surveys (e.g. the Net Promoter Score) being primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for our survey was drop-down:

[image: NPS mobile drop-down]

Answer (score 2):

Consider an alternative input type such as a horizontal slider. Not only would that fit within the screen width but it would also preserve screen real estate above and below since a slider has little height.

Another way to look at it is that any structure you use will influence the user.  You can't not influence them. Putting 1 first (as opposed to 10) probably has a bigger impact than having the options on two rows.

Comment: You can't not influence the user, but in the case of a standardized question that's widely used, you don't want to systematically influence users one way on one platform and another way on another.

Answer (score 0):

Use halfway chooseable 1-5 stars on the mobile.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't have the sensitivity required for many survey questions.

Answer (score 0):

Especially on mobile where most users hold their phone in a portrait position I'd recommend a vertical list of choices.

E.g. Similar to this (but numbers)

[image]

This solves several issues at once.

1. If you need room for longer labels you have it (e.g. "1 - very poor", "10 - Amazing Fantastic"
2. This ensures a really large hit target (mobile users are using their thumbs most of the time) e.g Fitts' Law

Finally I can think of nothing more frustrating than radio buttons and checkboxes on mobile... They are both beyond difficult to use.